# Regex to match all HTML tags contains <p> and </p>

Tags: regex

Through the code i got the output content as XML.
I have pair or multiple of html tags as follows:

December 10

Welcome to this space

Hai, Today is Tuesday

This a xml tag

I want a regular expression as below requirement:

As above  mentioned i want only one EMPTY pair Tag as

. I do not want the repeated EMPTY indefinite or definite pair tags.

Please help me in this regard to use regular expression to overcome the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to use the code block, your example is being parsed as html and not displaying correctly.

Comment: What do you want to do????? And by the way: parsing HTML with regular expressions is almost always a very bad decision.

Comment: You did see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags, right?

Comment: I have to agree to Stefan. Usually, the DOM or XML way is the right way to go. But still, it depends on what you want to do. If you only want to match one tag, and they're not nested, in my eyes, regexes are the way to go, since they are much cleaner and simpler in those cases. Being pragmatic in that case...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3):

The question mark makes the expression non-greedy, so that only the contents between two tags are matched, instead of the contents between the very first opening and the very last closing tag. *This is assuming you don't have nested p tags, else you're going to be in trouble with this one...*

```
/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/
```

Obviously, you're going to have to go with something like `preg_match_all` in PHP, depending on which language you use. You're going to find the contents of the tag in the first matching group.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `<` and `>`.

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't sure about this because of named capturing groups etc.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have nested p blocks. Again the same mistake parsing HTML codes with the Regex, DOM is used to parse HTML and not Regex. [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)